# centering div not working

Tags: html, css, less

I am trying to center the text and form field inputs in the #registration-code-entry .registration-code-entry-content div

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/yLX4F/

[image]

```
<div id="registration-code-entry">
    <div class="registration-code-entry-header"></div>

    <div class="registration-code-entry-middle">
        <div class="registration-code-entry-content">
            <form class="registration-form">

                <div class="field">
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="*First Name" class="required" />
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="*Last Name" class="required" />
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="*Email Address" class="required" />
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" />
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="optin">
                    <label for="optin" />Yes, I would like to receive more information</label>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="accept" class="required" />
                    <label for="accept">*I accept the <a href="#" class="view-official-rules">Official Rules</a>.</label>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="">
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="registration-code-entry-footer"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#registration-code-entry {
    height: 100px;
    width: 359px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 20px;
    background: transparent;

    .registration-code-entry-header {
        top: 0;
        background: transparent url('../images/form-header.png') no-repeat;
        width: 359px;
        height: 17px;
    }

    .registration-code-entry-middle {
        background: #713487;

        .registration-code-entry-content {
            border: 1px solid red;
            width: 350px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            color: #fff;

            form {

                display: inline-block;
                margin: 0 auto;

                .field {
                    margin: 10px 0;

                    input[type="email"], input[type="text"] {
                        padding: 5px;
                    }
                }

                input.submit-btn {
                    background: transparent url('../images/submit-btn.png') no-repeat;
                    width: 168px;
                    height: 59px;
                    display: block;
                    border: 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .registration-code-entry-footer {
        display: block;
        bottom: 0;
        background: transparent url('../images/form-footer.png') no-repeat;
        width: 359px;
        height: 11px;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're nesting your CSS. Are you using a preprocessor?

Comment: @Mathias yes, I am using less

Comment: Try and add `text-align: center` inside `.field`

Comment: @PeterHorvath I am doing my job, I am stuck on something and I am looking for an answer to my question.

Comment: And you might want to change to `display: block` inside form but I'm not sure what other element that will affect.

Comment: @Mathias add those two recommendations as an answer and I will accept it, that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `text-align: center`to `.field`. You can also change to `display: block` for `form` to make the form expand to the full width of the parent.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/yLX4F/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Centering the input ?

This will centering it :

```
.field input[type="text"], .field input[type="email"] {
    display:block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[Check This](http://jsfiddle.net/nucleo1985/yLX4F/1/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just change youre less :

```
 ...
.field {
  margin: 10px 0;
  input[type="email"], input[type="text"] {
    padding: 5px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
  }
}
...
```